# Regular expression with negative lookahead and negative lookbehind to check if my match IS NOT between [[ and ]]

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation, regex-replace

I'm trying to write a Python script which replaces occurrences of given keywords, in given md file, by themself between [[ and ]].

It will be used several times on the same files, so I don't want to end with, for instance,  FOO becoming [[FOO]], then [[[[FOO]]]] etc.

So I don't want FOO to be circle with [[ and ]].

The closest version I came up with is this:
`(?<!\[\[)\b(FOO)\b(?!\]\])`

The status of my test list is:

```
Should     match : lorem ipsum FOO dolor              ==> OK
Should NOT match : lorem ipsum [[FOO]]  dolor         ==> OK
Should NOT match : lorem [[ipsum FOO dolor]] sit amet ==> Not OK
Should NOT match : lorem [[ipsumFOOsolor]] sit amet   ==> OK
Should NOT match : [[lorem]]  [[ipsum-FOO&dolor-sit.pdf#page=130]] ==> Not OK
```

for reference, I would like to use this regexp in this python snippet:

```py
    for term in term_list:
        pattern = r'(?<!\[\[)\b(' + re.escape(term) + r')\b(?!\]\])'
        file_content = re.sub(pattern, r'[[\1]]', file_content)
```

What could be the regexp I need?
What is wrong with this approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Regular expressions are very poor at distinguishing "inside" and "outside" of brackets.

Comment: 1. In the first sentence what do you mean by "by themself"? Should `"FOO"` in `"lorem [ipsum FOO solor] sit"` be matched (note single brackets)? 2. What about `"lorem ipsumFOOsolor sit amet"`? 3. When brackets are present do they always appear in pairs, as in your examples (e.g., no `"...[[...[...]...]]..."`? 4. When brackets are present are they always balanced, as in your examples (e.g., no `"[[...]]...[[..."`)? 5. Can double brackets be nested (e.g., `"...[[...[[...]]...FOO...]]..."`? It would be best if you could answer by editing your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you might do, not taking nested `[[..[[..]]..]]` into account, is to get the `[[...]]` part out of the way and capture what you want to keep in a group.

Then use that group in the replacement, and leave the part that is only matched (not in the group) untouched.

You can [see the regex matches here](https://regex101.com/r/W82pHL/1).

This part in the pattern `(?:(?!\[\[|]]).)*` matches any charter that is not directly followed by either `[[` or `]]`

```
import re

pattern = r"\[\[(?:(?!\[\[|]]).)*\]\]|\b(FOO)\b"

s = ("lorem ipsum FOO dolor\n"
            "Should NOT match : lorem ipsum [[FOO]]  dolor\n"
            "Should NOT match : lorem [[ipsum FOO dolor]] sit amet\n"
            "Should NOT match : lorem [[ipsumFOOsolor]] sit amet\n"
            "Should NOT match : [[lorem]]  [[ipsum-FOO&dolor-sit.pdf#page=130]]")

result = re.sub(pattern, lambda x: f"[[{x.group(1)}]]" if x.group(1) else x.group(), s)
print(result)
```

Output

```
lorem ipsum [[FOO]] dolor
Should NOT match : lorem ipsum [[FOO]]  dolor
Should NOT match : lorem [[ipsum FOO dolor]] sit amet
Should NOT match : lorem [[ipsumFOOsolor]] sit amet
Should NOT match : [[lorem]]  [[ipsum-FOO&dolor-sit.pdf#page=130]]
```

Comment: This is a clever way to handle this problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: Good use of lambda

Answer (score 2):

I assume the following conditions are satisfied, as they are for all the examples given in the question.

- Single brackets are not present in the string. That is, any open bracket (`"["`) must be preceded or followed by exactly one open bracket. Similar for closed brackets (`"]"`).
- Double-brackets are always balanced, e.g., there is no `"[[...]]...[[..."`.
- Double-brackets are not nested, e.g., there is no `"...[[...[[...]]...FOO...]]..."`.
- The keyword string cannot be immediately preceded or followed by a word character (e.g., no `"...catFOO dog..."`, `"...cat FOOdog..."` or `"...catFOOdog..."`).

For example, `"FOO"` should be matched in these three strings:

```
lorem ipsum FOO dolor
lorem ipsum FOO dolor [[amet]]
[[lorem]] ipsum FOO dolor [[sit]] amet
```

but not in these six:

```
lorem ipsum [[FOO]] dolor
lorem [[ipsum FOO dolor]] sit amet
lorem [[ipsumFOOsolor]] sit amet
[[lorem]]
[[ipsum-FOO&dolor-sit.pdf#page=130]]
lorem ipsumFOO solor sit amet
```

---

If the conditions above are satisfied we may conclude that the keyword string is not within a double-bracket-delimited string if the following regular expression is matched.

```
\bFOO\b(?![^[\]]*(?:\[\[[^[\]]*]][^[\]]*)*]])
```

The idea is simple: given the assumptions above, particular that concerning the double-brackets being balanced, if `FOO` is followed later in the string by `"]]"`, possibly with intervening clauses of the form `[[...]]`, then `FOO` must be preceded in the string by `"[["`, possibly with intervening clauses of the form `[[...]]`, meaning that `"FOO"` is within a clause of the form `[[...FOO...]]`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PW49gA/1)<sup>1</sup>.

Note that "FOO" should be matched in the following string but it is not because the double-brackets do not satisfy the condition that they are balanced.

```
lorem FOO [[ipsum solor]] sit ]] amet
```

---

The regular expression can be broken down as follows. (One may hover over each element of the expression at the link to obtain an explanation of its function. To be clear, one should hover the cursor, not one's person.)

```
\bFOO\b       match the literal 'FOO' with pre- and post- word boundaries
(?!           begin a negative lookahead
  [^[\]]*     match >= 0 (`*`) characters other than '[' and ']'
  (?:         begin a non-capture group
    \[\[      match the literal '[['
    [^[\]]*   match >= 0 (`*`) characters other than '[' and ']'
    ]]        match the literal ']]'
    [^[\]]*   match >= 0 (`*`) characters other than '[' and ']'
  )*          end the non-capture group and execute it >= 0 times
  ]]          match the literal '[['
)             end the negative lookahead
```

<sup>1. I added a newline (`\n`) to the regular expression at the link in order to test multiple strings.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.  Your assumptions are correct execpt for "ipsumFOOdolor" that should not match, I expect  only whole words. It was not clear in my question, but implyed with my use of '\b's in my try. Anyway, on regex101, your solution seems fine with the tuning : `\bFOO\b(?![^[\]]*(?:\[\[[^[\]]*]][^[\]\n]*)*]])`. I'll try it in my code :-)

Comment: I fixed the regular expression as you suggested.

Comment: If you want to match balanced brackets, you would need either recursion or write a small parser which keeps track of the balancing. Your pattern will match FOO here `FOO [[ [[ test ]]` and they are not balanced. The pattern only looks to the right for the `]]` :-) You might write a balanced pattern using the regex PyPi module.

Comment: @Thefourthbird, I expect you noticed that I merely assumed that the double bracket are balanced and not nested. If that needed to be checked, your parser option would get my vote: easier to implement, test and maintain, easier for others to understand and far less likely to induce a migraine. More generally, I see many answers to SO questions that propose a regex that goes far beyond what was being asked (such as whether parentheses are balanced), even when the OP knows, but has not stated, that there is no need to make those tests because the data can be trusted.